# How to disable filtering and sorting for kendo grid column

Tags: jquery, sorting, kendo-grid, filtering

I am trying to disable the filtering and sorting of a kendo-grid column. The version of the kendo-grid is 2014.1.318. I cannot change the version because that is the library version used by the application (I introduce a plugin for it and reuse the libraries).

```
<script src="/Versions/v3.70/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My kendo grid is called resources-grid and the column is SourceValue.

```
var dest = $("#resources-grid").find("th[data-field='SourceValue']");
dest.data('filterable', destFilterableAndSortable);
dest.data('sortable', destFilterableAndSortable);
```

I expect the filtering icon to become hidden and the header of the column to stop supporting sort as link.

There isn't any changes in the behavior of the selected column and it is still filterable and sortable.

Comment: Don't you have to refresh that data source if you make those changes? The best place to set these values would be in the initial configuration.

Comment: Why not use `filterable: false` &  `sortable: false` ?

Comment: During the setup of the grid these option are enabled and I want them enabled. I want to disable(or enable again) these option (filtering and sorting) when some changes in my page are made out of the grid. I need to disable/hide these options. The data in the grid is fetched again and it is accurate. But the icon in the UI is still there and enabled.

Comment: Any suggestions?